# How do I position text field inside search bar with both components centralised?

Tags: html, css

Starting my learning from scratch so, I'm making a mock google home search page for practice. I'm trying to position a text field inside a search bar and have both at the centre of the web-page above a search button. The image below is what I've got so far:

[image: Search page with wrongly positioned components]

My code can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-lggo9r?file=GoogleSearch.html) however, for some reason the preview on stackBlitz isn't rendering it the same way as a standard web browser.

What CSS modifications do I need to make to achieve the correct positioning?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be many ways to do this. Here is how I did it the first time I tried. This is not the ONLY way to do this nor is it the BEST way to do it.

```css
.container {
    min-width: 400px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

a {
    margin: 0px 10px;
}

.nav-bar-links {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.search-button {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 2% 0px;
}

.search-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="search-container">
            <div class="nav-bar-links">
                <nav>
                    <a href="AdvancedSearch.html">Advanced Search</a>
                    <a href="GoogleImageSearch.html">Google Image Search</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <form action="https://google.com/search">
                <input class="text-field" type="text" name="Search Query">
                <button type="" class="search-button" value="Google Search" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

[I suggest you to go through the CSS basics documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout). Also try to do one thing at a time. If you are focusing on the layout, do not try to make the elements very good looking. Get the layout right first and then move on to make things pretty.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help but unfortunately this didn't work but rather reset the page to almost it's original state on my browser when i tested it.. everything went back to the top left corner of the page

Comment: check if you are properly linking your css file. Check the name and the path in the href.

Comment: Okay so, this aspect of the code snippet you gave me solved the problem `form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
`